# Subsetting a dictionary in Python using a list of keys - unhashable error

Tags: python, list

I am trying to subset a dictionary in python by using the keys in a list.  Here is what I have:

```
sub_set = dict((k, my_dict[k]) for k in tuple(my_list))
```

But I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

But I thought converting it to a tuple first would have solved that.

Comment: Please show us the contents of `my_list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List are unhashable. Tuple are hashable. Both are iterable.

> I thought converting it to a tuple first would have solved that.

Assuming from your example that `my_list` is a "list of list", probably you don't put the `tuple()` call at the right place:

```
sub_set = dict((tuple(k), my_dict[tuple(k)]) for k in my_list)
#               ^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^
#      convert the list k to a tuple
```

Or better:

```
sub_set = dict((k, my_dict[k]) for k in map(tuple,my_list))
#                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                                   map *inner* lists to tuples
```

See:

```
>>> my_dict = {(1, 2): "1;2", (2, 3): "2;3", (3, 4): "3;4" }
>>> my_list = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
>>> sub_set = dict((k, my_dict[k]) for k in map(tuple,my_list))
>>> sub_set
{(1, 2): '1;2', (2, 3): '2;3'}
```

Comment: Ah yes..it was indeed a list of lists. I could used a for loop to extract the contents into a regular list but your method looks more efficient.

Comment: @Cybernetic More "pythonic", Probably. More efficient, it is an other story: that being said, unless you have very specific needs, using `map(tuple, ...)` is more than "good enough" ! To cite Donald Knuth: _"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"_  and I would strongly favor readability over raw performances.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. What's in `my_list`?

```
In [2]: my_dict = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3}
In [3]: my_list = ['foo', 'baz']
In [4]: sub_set = dict((k, my_dict[k]) for k in tuple(my_list))
In [5]: sub_set
Out[5]: {'baz': 3, 'foo': 1}
```